# Pyinstaller does not recognize cv2 as a package

Tags: pyinstaller

I have an issue when generating an exe from python using PyInstaller.
PyInstaller reports the following warning:

60106 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cv2.py' from '…\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...

60112 WARNING: collect_dynamic_libs - skipping library collection for module 'cv2' as it is not a package.

60112 WARNING: collect_data_files - skipping data collection for module 'cv2' as it is not a package.

The generated code works fine on a computer where opencv is installed already but it fails on a "blank" desktop.

I tried using both commands but with the same result:

python -m PyInstaller --console --noupx --onefile --add-data="toto.ui;." toto.py

or

python -m PyInstaller --console --noupx --onefile --hidden-import cv2 --add-data="toto.ui;." toto.py

If you have any idea to help me, I would appreciate it deeply.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. In the conda environment where i was try to generate executable using pyinstaller, i had opencv installed using conda,  when i installed **opencv-python** using **pip** then problem was resolved.